# What is the ruby equivalent of Powershell (Get-ChildItem D:\SQLInstaller -Directory | ? {$_.Name -Like "SQL20*"}).Name

Tags: ruby, powershell

There are four possible names that the subdirectory under D:\SQLInstaller can have.

I want to use ruby(chef) to return the name of the directory like SQL20* into a variable.

I have tried various versions of Dir.entries and Dir.glob without any luck.

Comment: what variations have you tried?

Comment: This works, but it is super ugly.

Comment: a = Dir['D:/SQLInstaller/sql20*']
b = a.to_s
c = b.split('/')[2]
d = c.chop
e = d.chop
puts a
puts b
puts c
puts d
puts e

Comment: Wow okay try `Dir['D:/SQLInstaller/sql20*'].first.split("/").last` ? or maybe `require 'pathname'; Pathname.glob('D:/SQLInstaller/sql20*').first.basename.to_s`

Answer (score 0):

If you want all subdirectories:

```
subdirectories = Dir.children('D:/SQLInstaller').select { |c| File.directory?(c) }
```

If you want only subdirectories that match SQL20.*:

```
matching = Dir.children('D:/SQLInstaller').select { |c| File.directory?(c) && c =~ %r{SQL20.*} }
```

If you want only the first subdirectory that matches SQL20.*:

```
first_matching = Dir.children('D:/SQLInstaller').select { |c| File.directory?(c) && c =~ %r{SQL20.*} }.first
```

Comment: `each_child` would be better since it doesn't generate an intermediate Array. Also `select{}.first` can be `detect`